# Why GMail is accepting to send mail without Authentication?

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail, sendmail

```
public class SendMail {

  private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator 
  {

    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
      return new PasswordAuthentication("userID", "pwd");
    }
  }

   public void sendMail() throws Exception {
   String strFromIds = "xyz@gmail.com";
   String strToIds = "xyz@domain.com";
   String strSubject = "Sample Mail Subject.";
   String strContent = "Sample Mail Content";
   Properties objProperties = System.getProperties();
   objProperties.put("mail.smtp.host", "<smtp host name>");
   objProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
   objProperties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
   objProperties.put("mail.smtp.submitter", "<user id>");
   objProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
   objProperties.put("mail.debug", "true");
   Session objSMTPSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(objProperties, new  
                                                     SMTPAuthenticator());

   Message objMessage = new MimeMessage(objSMTPSession);
   objMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(strFromIds));
   InternetAddress[] objToAddress = new InternetAddress[1];     
   objToAddress[0] = new InternetAddress(strToIds);
   objMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, objToAddress);

   objMessage.setSubject(strSubject);

   Multipart objMultiPart = new MimeMultipart();
   MimeBodyPart objBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

   objBodyPart.setText(strContent);
   objMultiPart.addBodyPart(objBodyPart);

   objMessage.setContent(objMultiPart);

   Date objSentDate = new Date();
   objMessage.setSentDate(objSentDate);
   Transport.send(objMessage);
    objMessage = null;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    new SendMail().sendMail();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Exception in main :: " + ex);
    }
 }
}
```

By using the above code,i am able to send a mail to gmail user with the from address of GMail mail id(eg:xyz@gmail.com), without giving authentication details of gmail id,

here i gave my smtp ( company mail server ) server host name, and userid and pwd of my company mail server( which is given as smtp host)...

With these, i am sending mail as GMail user,,

But why GMAIL is accepting this type of mails.

Comment: This has nothing to do with GMail, could you rephrase your question and title? Example: "Why can I use my corporate mailserver to send mails using an arbitrary FROM address"

Answer (score 6):

You've discovered why there is spam.  :-)

You're sending the message through your company's mail server.  Your company's mail server doesn't appear to be checking whether the From address you use is valid for your mail server, so it's letting you use your Gmail address instead of your company address.  No, it doesn't check with Gmail to find out if it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail cannot sending mail without any authentication.

You can't Authenticate with wrong credentials. In another words if you have password (and gmail requires one) you can't log in without sending your password so you won't be able to send anything.

In general, you can, sure. In your concrete example code you are using GMail which does not allow anonymous sending.

From their references:

smtp.gmail.com (use authentication)
Use Authentication: Yes
Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587
Port for SSL: 465

An additional comment regarding your catch clause:

In my opinion you are heavily misusing the exception idea. A better aproach would be something like:

```
catch(Exception x)
 {
var s = x.Message;
if ( x.InnerException!=null )
{
    s += Environment.NewLine + x.InnerException.Message;
}

MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

Comment: sorry, i didn't get you, you saying it does not allow anonymous sending, But it allowing me to send mails as gmail user...

Comment: one doubt you said code ( var s = x.Message; ), i wrote in java, we can create var in javascript only...

Comment: yes because you are verified and authenticate user, your account information is verified and authenticated, that's why gmail gives you permission token to send mails, hope u understand.

Comment: ok, but with this if any one mis uses the mail id, then who will be responsibility..is that mistake of my company host server ( which is not authenticating that the from id is related to the host or not) or gmail ..