# Send Java email without authentication (no such provider exception: smtp)

Tags: java, email, authentication, jakarta-mail

The code I am currently using is as follows:

```java
String to = "....@gmail.com";
String from = ".....@gmail.com";
String host = "127.0.0.1";
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
try {
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                              new InternetAddress(to));
    message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");
    message.setText("This is actual message");
    Transport.send(message);
    System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
} catch (MessagingException mex) {
    mex.printStackTrace();
}
```

If I paste the above code in my Java `servlet` and run it, the following exception gets thrown: 
`javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: smtp`

I have also tried following the solutions outlined in these resources but to no avail: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559348/why-gmail-is-accepting-to-send-mail-without-authentication) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841632/how-i-send-email-without-authentication-using-java) [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816973/is-it-possible-to-send-mail-with-javamail-without-authentication) [link4](http://www.coderanch.com/t/559264/java/java/Sending-email-authentication).

Comment: do you have mail server running on ur localhost?

Comment: mail server means, can u explain...?

Comment: I don't want to confuse u here, u first need to check what "mx records" is. try this: try gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com as a host instead

Comment: instead of 127.0.0.1 use the smtp outgoing server of the provider, in your case is  "smtp.gmail.com"

Comment: i tried but getting same error only...

Comment: @Rami.Q still getting same error

Answer (score 1):

`NoSuchProviderException` means something is messed up in your JavaMail API configuration. Where and how have you installed the JavaMail jar file?

Also, in case it's not clear from the other responses, the only way you're going to be able to send mail without authentication is if you're running your own mail server. You can't do it with general purpose online e-mail services (*e.g.* Gmail).

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you included the the full stacktrace for the javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException and JavaMail debug output.  Because you are running this in a servlet container you could be running into [Bug 6668 -skip unusable Store and Transport classes](https://kenai.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6668).  Change your call to Transport.set to the following:

```
    final ClassLoader ccl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(Session.class.getClassLoader());
    try {
        Transport.send(message);
    } finally {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(ccl);
    }
```

That code will isolate which transport class the code is allowed to see.  That will rule out that bug in your code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you wanna use gmail to send emails from your program you need to define stmp host as gmail. Your current host "127.0.0.1" is localhost meaning your own computer? Do you have mail server running on your computer?

Here you can see some tutorial how to send an email using gmail: http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

If you're afraid to pass your normal gmail account details then create some kind of test email like kselvatest or something.

You are missing pretty much those:

```
final String username = "username@gmail.com";
final String password = "password";

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

So basicly all you need to add is:

1.login and password so JavaMail can use some gmail account

2.declare which mail server you wanna use

change `String host = "127.0.0.1";` to `String host = "smtp.gmail.com";`

3.set mail port

Comment: i asked without authentication

Comment: well you fooled around a bit with using gmail, recently i was able to send emails w/o auth but we had such way enabled by our admins within domain, but it would only work inside intranet

Comment: finally u are telling that we can't able to send mail w/o auth in gmail

Comment: yes, if you want to send emails with gmail you have to do it like I showed

Comment: then most of people given code for w/o in gmail in stack overflow itself, y that is not relevant code...?

Comment: well if you wanna use gmail you need to authenticate

Answer (score 0):

For this code you should get `javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 127.0.0.1, port: 25;` exception

But I suspect you have a jre issue. May be smtp implementation has a problem. Why don't you download java mail implementation from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html and add it to your project class path and try?

Comment: The latest JavaMail downloads are [here](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).